# password-ed ms-access 2007, corrupted db file, performance

Tags: c#, passwords, ms-access-2007

I work generally with c#/ms-access 2007, but some customers needs that the first seem to be dangerous with ms-access 2007 :
1- Can I set password without worried? Can I really save a corrupted file?
2- And what about performance with db file with password?

Comment: What kind of application we are talking about here? Is it a single user app? Or do you place your database in a Lan machine and reach it from different pc with concurrency problems?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have business app that i made by vs/c# , the dbms that i use is ACE12 with password, i am afraid from day that the file will be corrupted because it is encrypted with the password, can i resolve the problem with some existed tools?, the second, accdb with password is slower then accdb without password?

Comment: The file doesn't become corrupted just because you have set a password. With Access the main concerns are if there is a multiuser usage of the database that coupled with incorrect code or unexpected network failures could cause a corruption of the file (and this is probably the worry of your customers) As for the speed I think that you cannot notice any reasonable difference with or without password, but of course, you are in a better position than me to evaluate performance problems.

Comment: The main problem that i imagine with an encrypted file, if one day become a corrupted file, the chance to repair it is so little, does i am wrong?